# Configure what font is chosen when CSS says "font-family: Arial"

Tags: fonts, browser

On my Ubuntu box, when the CSS file says `font-family: Arial`, both Chrome and Firefox display the element in Arimo. I don't like this behaviour because Arimo has a small bug that matters for me. How do I change it to some other font (not necessarily Arial which I don't even have installed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If simply uninstalling Arimo is not an option, then, at least in 18.04, editing `/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf` (the actual XML part, not the comments at the top) should help. Otherwise, removing `fonts-croscore` would do it.

Answer (score 0):

[WhatFont](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm) is a Chrome extension that will tell you specifically which font in the font stack is being loaded.

Comment: Actually, I can see it in the DevTools without any extension :) But how do I configure it?